# Adding a css attribute to a class after transitionend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing some animation works with css keyframes.First i need to keep the element's opacity zero then after the animation is end then it would be one(1).I have wrote some jQuery codes and  still not works.

### Css codes

```
.slider_img {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 24%;
    top: 50vh;
    animation-name: dropImg;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.slider_img').on("webkitTransitionEnd", function(){
        $('.slider_img').css('opacity', 1);
    })  
});
```

What sould i do now

Comment: You should have `-webkit-transition` property defined over element.. Either in `CSS` or `Inline-CSS`

Comment: Now you will open developer's  tool & will check for any error . If you can understand & find the root cause of the error you will resolve by yourself else you can update this question with the error

Comment: @Rayon does not work yet

Comment: You do not need jQuery for this. Just use multiple animations, and set a delay to the opacity change.

Comment: @BramVanroy how can i do that?I need to change opacity to 1 at last

Comment: Can you first post your HTML as well? Only the relevant parts ofcourse.

Comment: And also add the keyframes code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    var sliderImg = $('.slider_img'),
        delay = sliderImg.css('animation-duration').replace("s","") * 1000;

    setTimeout(function(){
        sliderImg.css('opacity', 1);
    }, delay);  
});
```

Comment: doesn't work:( it adds opacity : 1 before starting transition

Comment: Delay was in incorrect format, see edit to `delay = `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your animation starts when your page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aDuration = parseInt($('.slider_img').css('animation-duration').slice(0, -1)) * 1000;
    var aDelay = parseInt($('.slider_img').css('animation-delay').slice(0, -1)) * 1000;

    var delay = aDuration + aDelay;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.slider_img').css('opacity', 1);
    }, delay);
});
```

**EDIT:** Added the delay from `animation-delay`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the wrong event `transitionend` when you should be looking for `animationend` (plus of course you will need all the prefixes). For example:

```
$('.slider_img').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function() { 
    $('.slider_img').css('opacity', 1);
});
```